# sqoop jobs data getting stored in edgenode and namenode as well

Tags: cluster-computing, sqoop

When I submit a sqoop job to the cluster using edgenode, the data is getting stored in the edgenode, name node and data-nodes as well. I noticed this when i clicked on one of the file in  hdfs filesystem on 50070 .  The cluster i use is on premise. I am not sure what is the mistake. I think it could be with cluster set up. Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

The chance could be that you might have configured your "edgenode/namenode" as "datanode" as well. If you are using any distribution like Cloudera/Hortonworks then please check the number of hosts configured to the datanode and remove the edgenode/namenode hosts , if it is there.